# Flexbox first line of wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How to edit first line of `flex-wrap`?

Here is a example that I want to achieve, on resizing, first line of wrap has some blank space or `<div>` after it:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can go with the following solution:

```css
div.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width:25%;
}
div.container div:first-child {
  margin-bottom:60px;
}
div.container div {
  border:1px solid red;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```